# REST API, get a list of resources by a specific value - naming conventions

Tags: java, rest

Let's say I have an ecommerce site with customer and orders, as would be expected :)
I have some doubts about resource naming, especially the resource that return all orders by a specific user_id

Some proposals:

```
1. /orders/?userid={userid}
2. /orders/customer/{userid}
3. /customers/{userid}/orders
```

Not my doubts:

1. As a resource that return ALL orders SHOULD NOT exists, the userid become a fundamental parameter, therefore it's not optional as query parameter may suggest
2. Maybe my favourite one, but I'm a bit perplexed if the previous one is the better choice
3. This indeed follow the bad practice 'don't nest the resource'. I don't like to output a different entity (order) from the base (customers)

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I voted to close this question due to its primarily opinionated flavor. As Cassio already mentioned, the characters in a URI are not of relevance, hence any URI you provide a client with is fine. Why is that? The URI as a whole is a pointer to the content of a resource and it shouldn't make sense to a client as it is just to alluring for a client to consider a resource returning a certain [type](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html). What happens here is that a orders resource is considered to return certain fields instead of a common representation format

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an `Order` document and it contains `customer` field. So, the following REST API is consistent for your domain:

```
GET /orders/customer/{userid}
```

This is not the only solution,[REST Resource Naming Guide](https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/)

Answer (score 1):

REST is an architectural style and not a cookbook for designing URIs. So REST itself  doesn't care about the URI spelling, as long as it conforms with the [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).

It's totally up to you to pick the URIs that better identify your resources.

---

> Any suggestions?

Answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. What you'll read from this point is my personal opinion, entirely based on my professional experience.

- If your users must be authenticated to view their orders and they only have access to their own orders, you could have something like `/me/orders` or even `/orders` and then implicitly filter the orders according to the current user who's authenticated.
- Otherwise, you could use `/orders?user={user}`, where `/orders` indicates a collection of orders and `?user={user}` expresses a filter over that collection.
- For a more advanced scenario, however, you may consider a `/orders/search` endpoint supporting `POST` requests, which allow you to have a payload that describes your search criteria.

Comment: No, the site Is for backoffice, so any granted user can view customer's order

Comment: @FabrizioStellato Then consider `GET /orders?user={user}`. For a more advanced scenario, you may look into `POST /orders/search`, allowing you to have a payload that describes your search criteria.